# Bootstrap Modal popup does not allow focus on the parent input elements when we click on the parent input element

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-11, sharepoint-online

we have a bootstrap modal which shows icon, and on click of the icon we are trying to show a small window similar to chat box, but the problem we are facing is the when the icon is clicked, the chat box opens up but the main problem

1. the chat box input does not get the focus -
2. The chat box input gets focus only the when the modal is closed

This issue occurs only in IE it works fine in google chrome & Edge provided if we remove TabIndex=-1 property for the bootstrap modal.

Chatbox is the parent element here

how can we resolve this issue in IE?

Comment: You can try to refer the solution provided by community member. If issue persist than I suggest you to post your sample code. We will try to test your code with IE and try to suggest you possible solution for the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is problem with the bootstrap model. Responsible event listner in the bootstrap instantly focus on the model. So we have to focus off from the model once the window is opened. You can use the below code to do that.

```
$("mymodal").on('shown.bs.modal',function(){
    $(document).off('focusin.modal');
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: @Pradeep, Did you tried this? Let me know if you still facing an issue. Else mark it as answer.

Comment: What would be solution while using in ReactJs and reactstrap.github.io